# First word in sentence has bigger font-size: container element cuts it off on top

Tags: overflow, font-size, css

The main text of my website's first word has a significant larger font-size than the rest. For some reason or another the container that contains the text cuts the first word off on top. Probably because the line-height of the first word is identical to the rest of the text and thus the container is not able to calculate its own height properly.

Codepen snippet: http://codepen.io/sardasht/pen/maJup (I've included the full contents of my css file to be able to debug properly, so will not embed this here. If this is requested, I'd happily edit my post to include it, but it will be ~300 lines of text)

If I increase the line-height of the first word, the rest of the text which is on the same line gains the same line-height and thus jumps up from the rest of the text below. If I add a margin-top to the container element, the first word is not cut off anymore, but then the bottom line of the text is cut off.

I played with overflow: visible/hidden as well on all parent elements, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

The `p` element has `line-height: 1.5em`, which will set the height of the text lines inside it. Because of the `em` unit, the height is determined based on the font size, and it's the font size set for the `p` element that is used, so the line height won't increase because of the larger font size set on a child element.

Comment: Got that. When I set the line-height to 1.5 (without em), it does not cut off the first word anymore. But now the problem re-occurs that the first line jumps up from the rest of the text. I understand the cause of the problem, but have not found a solution yet to make the first word have a bigger font-size, while keeping it in line with the rest of the text-flow, and regaining the same line-height for all lines. Any clue on how to accomplish that?

Comment: @grrrbytes: Text is aligned around the base line, so if you want the first work not to stick up above the rest of the text you need to remove it from that text line. You can use `float: left;` to make the rest of the text flow around it, and set a specific height on it if you don't want it to push out more than one line.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using a line-height declaration that isn't set in px, or ems.

`p, span { line-height:1 }`

I also tried

`span { line-height:0.8 }`

which seemed to give the very least amount of top "push", but I only viewed it in FF on a Mac.

I've noticed, with fonts, that their heights and widths are rendered differently from browser to browser. And this can be exacerbated with fonts that haven't been given proper leading, kerning, etc. This can cause "odd" line breaks, which causes a 'problem' with set block heights -- especially going from FF, and Chrome to IE. FWIW.

**EDIT:**
http://jsfiddle.net/mvf6j/

Setting the line-height to 1 (of the child) equates to 100% of the parent's line-height; thus, in your example code 1 = 1.5em. In my fiddle/example, 1 = 1em (even with the child being a 2em font). It's inheritance. It makes the child relative to the parent. And takes the guess work out, if you should want to change the parent's size. All of that ease in sizing/relationships disappears when you set explicit line-heights to the children.